# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04, having Installed 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, system-installation

I have currently installed Ubuntu 16.04 along side Windows 10. After some updates I can not boot any more to Ubuntu and I couldn’t fix it. So I decided its time to move on to Ubuntu 18.04. I have live USB with new Ubuntu. I don’t mind losing Ubuntu data. During the installation process it shows option: 
"Erase Ubuntu 16.04 and reinstall"

I prefer option "Something else".
When choosing the partition with Ubuntu 16.04 on it, and configurating it as a mounting point for /, I encounter this: "You cannot undo this operation. Please note that the resize operation may take a long time". Should I be worried?

Is it safe to reinstall this way? Specially because i read that 18.04 uses newer GRUB version.

Comment: If you install using the 'something-else' and select your current partitions ensuring you have the 'format' box **unticked** (ie. 16.04 partitions **without format**) the installer will take note of additional programs you added to your system, erase system directories, install new 18.04 system, then add back the additional programs you had installed (in 16.04 IF available in 18.04's repositories), then ask to reboot. It won't touch your user files as long as you don't format.  It's what I'd use (but note I'd have backed up any data before hand regardless; the 'format' box is easily missed!)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your answer. I would actually prefer to format and clean all the data and previous programs from this partition. I already backed up all I needed. I am just unsure if some problems may arise for windows (although its on separate partition) which is installed alongside Ubuntu, or problems with Grub, because of this kind of reinstallation?

Comment: If windows is not in hibernate mode (which includes fast-boot enabled as it's just a wake from prepared hibernated-file) I would expect grub to correctly detect & setup for everything. It'll just replace whatever 'grub' was there prior anyway. I rarely have issues, but should I, I just boot & `sudo update-grub` & watch to ensure everything is detected (`grub-install` if necessary); if not detected a `mount` usually fixes or tells me why it wasn't detected (ie. something hibernated)  Grub I find easy to fix, it's just we don't use it enough to remember all command/options.. (*so search online*)

Comment: Thanks for help!